# SASS Mixin Substituting One Argument for Another

Tags: css, sass

So, I'm just starting to learn SASS, and I thought I'd write a quick mixin to prepend all of the vendor prefixes to a statement. So I wrote this:

```
@mixin prefix( $style, $value ) {
  $style: $value;
  -o-#{$style}: $value;
  -moz-#{$style}: $value;
  -webkit-#{$style}: $value;
  -ms-#{$style}: $value;
}

header {
  @include prefix( transform, rotate(90deg) );
}
```

However, for some reason I can't fathom, this produces the output:

```
header {
  -o-rotate(90deg): rotate(90deg);
  -moz-rotate(90deg): rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-rotate(90deg): rotate(90deg);
  -ms-rotate(90deg): rotate(90deg); }
```

Evidently it is substituting the second argument for the first argument.  It produces the same output [here](http://sass-lang.com/try.html) as on my server.  I hope someone can shed some light on why this is happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that not only has the value of `$style` been replaced with the value of `$value`, but you also aren't getting the non-prefixed rule - you should have `transform: rotate(90deg);` as the first output rule before `o-transform`. That should be a clue that the problem is in your first line.

And it is: that first line should be

`#{$style}: $value;`

Just like in all the subsequent rules, to get the literal contents of `$style` to be printed, you have to use the pound-sign decorator. Without it, SASS interprets that line as variable assignment.